# How to get status code of program piped to linux dialog command

Tags: linux, bash-scripting, code, status, dialog

I am trying to use Linux `dialog` to prepare simple installer for Ubuntu. The actual command is:

```
  dpkg -i package.deb 2>&1 | dialog --programbox "Installing..." 10 100
```

I want `dialog` to display any output produced by the `dpkg` command whether it is normal output or error message, so I redirect stderr to stdout. This works.

The problem is that I need status code of the `dpkg` command after both commands ended. Just to know if the `dpkg` did its job or not. Unfortunately, after these commands ended I can only get status code of the `dialog` command...

Anyone knows how to obtain status code of the `dpkg` command from above example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you search is the [pipestatus](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html):

```
dpkg -i ... | dialog ...
echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]} # this contains the exit code of the dpkg command.
```

See that example:

```
$ false | true | false | true
$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
1 0 1 0
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!